# Should 2 different questions that lead to the same answer be marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

I've [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815778/how-to-keep-special-double-quote-in-a-string-in-vb-net-unicode-u0093-and-u00) which was marked [as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665510/using-left-double-quotation-marks-in-strings-in-vb).

I agree that both question leads to the same answer, but I think both questions are different. Should it really be considered a duplicate?

**Question 1** : Why is Visual Studio replacing `“` and `”` with `"` ?

**Question 2** : Why does `dim x as string = "“"` result in a compile error?

**Answer** : Because VB considers `“` and `”` as equivalent to `"`.

I'm also asking because, while I feel it isn't a duplicate, I fail to see how I could change my question since it's seems clear enough already and I also know ***The*** answer and agree it's valid for both questions.

Lastly, the [help center states](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) :

> The fundamental goal of closing **duplicate questions** is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.

Comment: Ugh, now that I think about it. This should probably be on meta.stackexchange...

Comment: Why?  It's a Visual Studio-specific question that you're asking about.

Comment: I meant this question. Not the one I asked on SO. Visual studio is unrelated.

Answer (score 7):

Reopening only makes sense, in this specific instance, if *you can't get what you need at the original question.*

Since your question was fully answered at the duplicate, it might benefit the community if your particular question is linked to the duplicate, so that future viewers can find the original.

Don't get me wrong; I'm a big believer in questions being essentially the same question, if they're to be marked as duplicate.  But there's one exception, and that is specific questions for which a more generalized canonical/reference question fully restates the overall issue, and provides a comprehensive solution to the specific problem.

We gave gold badge holders the ability to close questions as duplicates like this unilaterally, because we believe that they have the necessary knowledge in the problem domain to identify duplicates in a sensible way.

Comment: Well, I didn't get to *stop visual studio behavior* although I don't really want to stop it, because of the answer.