# Do closed questions contribute to question bans?

Tags: support

The help page doesn't mention it and I don't think the 2-3 developer comments mention it. But do closed questions contribute to bans if they don't have score <= 0 ?

I know the formula is not disclosed but the correlation factors have been disclosed so users can avoid them.

Also do duplicate questions contribute to question bans?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: They should. Keep your questions on-topic and you'll avoid a ban.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all closed questions contribute to question bans. See [Breaking down question blocks - let's talk about rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits/236947#236947):

> It [seems that duplicates count the same as other closure reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266364/why-was-my-question-marked-duplicate-citing-an-existing-similar-answer) for this system. [...]

Comment: So I often object closing duplicates base on better answers instead of ask time, consider a user asked a question and which is not a duplicate of any question, and later another user asked a duplicate but it has better answers and the first question is closed, then it passed the question ban risk for the former user suddenly

Comment: @amuse if the duplicate is well presented - so that it tends to pop up in relevant web searches - then users "passing through" it on their way to dupe target are likely to vote it up (at least that's the way I tend to do) and these upvotes will offset the effect of close