# Is it okay to duplicate a poor question if it does not have an answer and looks unlikely to be improved?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I'm referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355521/access-denied-error-in-ie-console-from-ng-view-in-angularjs) where I am having a similar issue and want to post a very similar but better question. I would, for example, post the relevant error message and the full code involved.

I may be being premature here but the user in question has been active since I requested the error message and has not posted it.

What is the best method of approach to this scenario or should I just post my own question?

Comment: Since you already have a bounty on it, I would at least wait that out. If you have something relevant to add you can do that in comments or, if it would pertain to your problem and the OP's, then edit the post with the useful information

Comment: Adding to what @codeMagic said, you did only post your comment an hour ago, and the question was posted quite a while ago. The OP may be looking to see if they can find or recreate that information. In other words, don't rush. Give the OP a bit more time, and even if that doesn't pan, your bounty might get that question an answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255984/839601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mark a question as a duplicate, you have to find an instance where a question has been both asked before and ***has an answer*** (the only exception being if the same person has asked both questions). As such, if I understand things correctly a new question on the same topic as that older question wouldn't be eligible to close as a duplicate, and in fact if your new question got an answer, you could potentially close the old lower-quality question as a duplicate of the new one.

You could probably find a low-quality post that's asked almost anything at one time or another. You're only creating redundancy if the question you're asking has already been asked and answered properly.

Comment: That seems reasonable