# What to do with bad duplicate closings

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

For a while I've been seeing a trend where a question is closed as a duplicate where the questions have a rough amount of overlap, but aren't duplicates in the sense of the word.

Take the question "[Java what mean % operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972467/java-what-mean-operator)" for example. The question asks what the % operator does in Java, which happens to be the modulo operator. This question was closed as a duplicate for "[What's the syntax for mod in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java)"?

To me, this is a poor duplicate. They are in a sense opposite questions, or one question is the "answer" to the other. I've been seeing more and more duplicate closings like this. For someone that is probably just getting the hang of Java, that "duplicate" would confuse me. How is this helping the OP?

Am I being too sensitive to the concept of a duplicate? I understand that there must be *some* leeway in what is considered a duplicate since it would be rare for two questions to be truly identical, but I think this example of many is a stretch.

Comment: I consider another question where the *answers* also answer the later question, as valid dupe target. In the end, the user gets their answer here. *`%` is the modulus operator*. If you have a better duplicate, by all means reopen and re-close (if you have a relevant gold tag badge) or leave a comment to that effect while you vote to reopen. Asking for help in a chat room can be effective there.

Comment: I must also say that a bad question like the example you gave can attract a lot of low-quality answers, and a swift dupe close can be helpful in avoiding that. The 6 answers on that post could have been avoided altogether, none of them add anything that could not have been found elsewhere on Stack Overflow already.

Comment: I've got my stopwatch running for the time it takes someone to trot out the old "So 3+2 and 35/7 are duplicates, huh?" chestnut.

Comment: So 3+2 and 35/7 are duplicates, huh?

Comment: @gnat: not sure that is the best dupe target here; I briefly looked for one that explains the goals of duplicate closing from a more general perspective but didn't find it yet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters something like [Should 2 different questions that lead to the same answer be marked as duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255981/839601)

Comment: @gnat: this duped post: [Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266244) covers the issues a little better, I think. There is certainly the *3 + 2 and 35 / 7* chestnut there to prove it. :-P

Comment: @gnat: I reversed the dupe link on that one and duped this one to it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters upon re-checking involved questions, your way seems to make good sense to me

Answer (score 2):

Anyone trying to find an answer to the question will get their answer if they go to the duplicate and look at the answers there.

The duplicate has thus clearly served its purpose, and is valuable.

Clearly in such a case the fact that the questions aren't exactly the same *isn't relevant to them getting answered* and as such it's entirely fine for them to be closed as duplicates.

If the differences in the question meant that going to the dupe target would not result in an answer to the question, or resolve the problem, *then* the questions wouldn't be duplicates.