# Unique questions with similar answers

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Recently got a 4 year old [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961215/escaping-ampersand-character-in-sql-string) of mine flagged for being a duplicate. The wording of the prompt says: `This question may already have an answer here`. The piece that confuses me is that in this situation, while the answers are in fact the same, the questions are substantively different.

In my mind, unique questions with the same answer still have value, since it's typically not obvious without expertise that the answers are the same. I think the fact that my question has about the same views in half the time is a testament to the fact that it's still adding value.

That said, the wording of the prompt would seem to imply that I'm wrong on this one. Am I reading too far into the prompt? Is this duplicate mark valid?

Comment: I don't follow what's not clear - 'This question may already have an answer here' is not saying 'This question has already been asked', it's saying your question already has the answer. Isn't that correct in this case? In other words, it would result in duplicate answers, not necessarily a duplicate question.

Comment: Also, because duplicates stick around, anyone who searches either like you posed the question or how the original question was posed, will still end up seeing the correct answer, right?

Comment: @TimMalone The piece that's not clear to me is that the question is marked a duplicate, but the question is not a duplicate. Only the answers are duplicates.

Comment: Are you suggesting there should be a new feature to mark answers as duplicates..?

Comment: A bit nit-picky maybe, but if you mean [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118190/how-do-i-ignore-ampersands-in-a-sql-script-running-from-sql-plus) it's about the **same** views in half the time, not double. (Though your point still holds)

Comment: @River sorry, you're totally right, I meant to imply it was getting them twice as fast and mis-wrote.

Comment: Ironically, isn't this topic similar to [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate?lq=1)?

Answer (score 14):

> unique questions with the same answer still have value . . . I think the fact that my question has about twice the views in half the time is a testament to the fact that it's still adding value.

Of course they do. That's why we don't *delete* duplicate questions. Rather, we keep them around, linking them to the other question that contains the answer. This way, as you point out, people who stumble across version B of the question will be directed to version A, where they will find their answer.

> The wording of the prompt says: This question may already have an answer here.

You say that confused you, but I am struggling to see how.

First of all, it does say ***may*** have an answer here. It is entirely possible that the person who proposed the duplicate target was wrong. Your question has not been officially marked as a duplicate, someone just flagged it as *possibly* being one. Going forward, the community will have a chance to agree or disagree with that proposal. If five trusted users agree and vote to mark your question as a duplicate, then it will officially be a duplicate and the message displayed will change. If a consensus cannot be reached, the duplicate flag will age away and no change will be made to your question (other than the humble comment beneath your question, which some people may still find useful).

Second, it is phrased precisely as it should be. It doesn't say "This exact same question may have already been asked here." Rather, it says that the question may already have an answer. Isn't that really the point of asking questions—to get the answer? If we already have an answer to the question, shouldn't we be pointing people to that answer, even if the question was phrased a little differently?

> since it's typically not obvious without expertise that the answers are the same

A very good point. This is precisely why we do not *punish* people for asking questions that end up being duplicates, and also why we give users who hold a gold badge in an applicable tag the ability to instantly mark a question as a duplicate. These gold tag-badge holders have shown that they possess the expertise needed to realize that two different-looking questions are, in fact, the same.

(I should point out again that the person who proposed your question was a duplicate did *not* hold a gold tag badge in any of the relevant topics and therefore was not able to single-handedly mark your question as a duplicate. He only flagged it, making a proposal.)

---

There is, of course, a larger issue here—namely, is the fact that two questions have identical answers sufficient grounds to make them duplicates. I'd say the community is fairly divided on that issue. The consensus is *generally* no, but there are exceptions where repeating minor variations on the same theme because a question is phrased differently just doesn't make sense.
Related reading:

- [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)
- [Can a question be a duplicate if it's totally different?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different)
- [Should 2 different questions that lead to the same answer be marked as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255981/should-2-different-questions-that-lead-to-the-same-answer-be-marked-as-duplicate)
- [What to do with an almost-duplicate question with a better answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294643/what-to-do-with-an-almost-duplicate-question-with-a-better-answer)